# SQL Server Server query - Count distinct DateTime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

Supposing we have the following records in an SQL Server table.

```
Date
19/5/2009 12:00:00 pm
19/5/2009 12:15:22 pm
20/5/2009 11:38:00 am
```

What is the SQL syntax for getting something like this one?

*Date* **Count**
*19/5/2009* **2**
*20/5/2009* **1**

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: Which RDBMS? The answer differs for T-SQL, P/L SQL, etc...

Comment: Sorry, fixed it in title. MS-SQL. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to do any grouping on a Date only version of your datefield, such as this.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), YourDateColumn, 101),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), YourDateColumn, 101)
```

I usually do this though, as it avoids conversion to varchar.

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(yy, YourDateColumn),
    DATEPART(mm, YourDateColumn),
    DATEPART(dd, YourDateColumn),
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(yy, YourDateColumn),
    DATEPART(mm, YourDateColumn),
    DATEPART(dd, YourDateColumn)
```

EDIT: Another way to get just the date part of a datetime

```
DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, YourDateColumn))
```

Comment: While it still converts to a varchar, you could convert it back to a datetime (giving you 12:00AM on that date), or you could take the results of your datepart's and convert that to a datetime.

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on your database engine. For SQL Server 2008 (and future versions), you can use the `date` type to do this.

```
select
    convert(date, date_column_name) as Date,
    count(1) as Count

from table_name

group by convert(date, date_column_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS). Example for Mysql:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%e/%c/%Y') as `date`, COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: This only groups by the year. He wanted the full date

Answer (score 0):

What RDBMS are you on? Using Sybase, your query would look like this:

```
select date(datetimeColumn) as myDate, count(*) as myTotal
from thisTable
Group by myDate
Order by myTotal, myDate
```

Answer (score 0):

After Googling found this one too...

SELECT   CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Expr1 AS FLOAT)) AS DATEtime) AS Expr1,

COUNT(*) AS Expr2

FROM        MY_TABLE

GROUP BY

CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Expr1 AS FLOAT)) AS DATEtime)

The cons?

1. High speed execution
2. The results returned are in the original locale. Ex for Greek 19/5/2009

Thank you all