# Selecting distinct date (not time) from a very large table with datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, group-by, distinct

I have a large table I have been playing with the query analyzer and looking for the best way to do this.

The table is like this:

```
name         rows        reserved     data         index_size   unused
table_name   110980132   7802944 KB   6119784 KB   1679320 KB   3840 KB
```

And has these columns:

```
 ID int, time_stamp datetime, value1 float, value2 float, value3 float....
```

These `time_stamps` are dates with times. I need to find an easy way, without storing anything, to be able to get just the date portions for the table. Eventually, I may need to know just the day + hour part (and not the whole time portion). At the moment, I just need to know what the last 30 days we had data for are (sometimes days are missing at this point, this question/query will ultimately not just be looking for the last x days, but all the days, or whatever).

What is the best way to do this considering performance and time? I've played with `group by`, `distinct`, `top x`, `rank()`, temp tables, views... some things are better than others but nothing I am doing seems to be great.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to add an additional index Daterow, you can Group by Cast(Floor(Cast(time_stamp as Float)) as Datetime)

Comment: The best bet in my opinion would be to (1) create a "date-only" computed column (which would be **a lot easier** in SQL Server **2008**), (2) make sure you can **persist** that computed column, and (3) put an index on it. That way, the computed column would always contain just the date part of your `time_stamp`, it would be indexed (you could also add some `INCLUDE` columns into the equation, possibly), and that should allow you to get semi-decent performance. But it requires storing an extra column .....

Comment: yeah... i was using dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, time_stamp)).  google just told me i can do this: select distinct top 30... i was trying before but just with the things in the wrong order.  i put an index on the time_stamp column, i am not sure if it is doing anything or not but this combination seems to work very, very well.

Comment: i have the power to add a column but i can't really justify it for only this...

Comment: you can get the efficient answer from : [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7712658/1530742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to using T-SQL batches, instead of a single query, then you can make use of indexes like this:

```
create table #tmp (date datetime primary key clustered);
declare @pivot datetime;
  insert #tmp
  select TOP(1) datediff(d,0,time_stamp)
    from tbl
order by time_stamp desc;
while @@rowcount > 0 and (select count(*) from #tmp) < 30
begin
      insert #tmp
      select TOP(1) datediff(d,0,time_stamp)
        from tbl
       where time_stamp < (select min(date) from #tmp)
    order by time_stamp desc;
end;
```

All this requires of you is a good index on `time_stamp`, and it will perform exactly 30 seeks (or less) on that index. Very surgical and quick.  I threw it up as a concept, so obviously the 2 scalar subqueries in there can be easily optimised.

Comment: can you tell me what a "good index" on time_stamp would be?  please.  i'm not good with indexes/indices... i have a textbook understanding but can't always tell when they are needed or how they are needed.

Comment: I should have said "helpful". Indexes can only be good, in a sense. Just create it `create index ix_tblname_time on tblname(time_stamp desc)`

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Get the earliest date (without time) you want
DECLARE @smallestDate datetime = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -30, GETDATE()), 0)

-- Select the distinct dates
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, time_stamp), 0) AS [Date]
FROM yourTable
WHERE time_stamp > @smallestDate
```

Here's some performance comparison
[Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)

Comment: that's what i was doing... but i don't know the earliest date.  because... i assume 30 days, 60 days... but i might have other constraints... like where value is in valid range for type x or something.  i can assume double my desired range (so if i need 30 days of data, i can assume that will happen in 60 days) but that ultimately takes as long as just running it through the whole thing and i will for sure get what i need.