# I need a query to count the number of user instances for each distinct timestamp in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is my data table:

```
userid  timestamp
------------------------
user1   2017-08-15 17:00
user1   2017-08-15 17:00
user1   2017-08-15 17:00
user2   2017-08-15 17:00
user2   2017-08-15 17:00
user3   2017-08-15 17:00
user1   2017-08-15 18:00
user1   2017-08-15 18:00
user2   2017-08-15 18:00
user2   2017-08-15 18:00
user2   2017-08-15 18:00
user3   2017-08-15 18:00
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
userid    countoftimestamp
-----------------------------
user1     3_2017-08-15 17:00
user2     2_2017-08-15 17:00
user3     1_2017-08-15 17:00
user1     2_2017-08-15 18:00
```

and so on.

Comment: "I need a query" is not a question. Have you considered hiring a programmer?

Comment: This is not a spoonfeeding site.  Please show what you attempted and what happened with that attempt.

Comment: Don't `concat` the count onto the time-stamp... keep it in a separate column so you don't have to parse it later to use it... and so you don't change the datatype of the time-stamp. With that said, both solutions below answer the question, and this is a duplicate of 100 other questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Comment: Wrong link for the duplicate, though it is as well.[Here is a better duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887822/sql-server-server-query-count-distinct-datetime-field)

Comment: @scsimon While I agree with you 100%, I've had to feed downstream applications with some ridiculous requirements and formats.

Comment: True @JohnCappelletti and hence my +1 on your post, but i'd bet a bounty that isn't the case here :D

Comment: @scsimon lol..  I'm sure you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that I used varchar(16) to truncate your timestamp down to minutes (excluding seconds and milliseconds)

**Example**

```
Select userid
      ,countoftimestamp = cast(sum(1) as varchar(25))+'_'+convert(varchar(16),timestamp,20)
 From  YourTable
 Group By userid,convert(varchar(16),timestamp,20)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: 2005 does not have concat :(

Comment: @SyedUmairRizvi Sorry I missed that.  One moment for a quick update

Comment: @SyedUmairRizvi Updated for 2005

Comment: @SyedUmairRizvi Happy it helped

Comment: You are great , and kind  . :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT userid, timestamp, count(*)
FROM datatabable
GROUP BY  userid, timestamp
```